# I do not understand this code. Why r's decimal, octal, hexadecimal value show garbage value?

Tags: c

This is the code-

```
  int j;
   printf("Enter the number:");
   scanf("%c",&j);

   printf("You have enter the decimal number %i \n",j);
   printf("You have enter the octal number %o\n",j);
   printf("You have enter the hexadecimal number %x\n",j);
   printf("You have enter the character %c\n",j);
```

This is my output:

```
Enter the number:r
You have enter the decimal number 4201074 
You have enter the octal number 20015162
You have enter the hexadecimal number 401a72
You have enter the character r
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or Java or Python?

Comment: 1 . do not spam tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` expects a `char *` as a parameter.  You're instead passing in an `int *`.

Using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is why you're seeing strange results.  What's *probably* happening behind the scenes is that only the first of the (presumably) 4 bytes of the `int` variable `j` are written to, leaving the rest uninitialized and containing whatever garbage was there previously.

Change the type of `j` to `char` and you should get the results you expect.